# Python Selenuim - UnicodeEncodeError 'charmap' codec can't encode

Tags: python, selenium

I keep getting this error when I try to print or use `driver.source_page`.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1494-1498: character maps to <undefined>
```

Not only with selenium, also with request and urllib3. I tried several solutions but none of them worked.
such as `str()`,`.encode("utf-8-sig"` OR `"utf-8")`,
`BeautifulSoup(source,from_encoding="utf-8")`.

my code:

```
import base64;from bs4 import BeautifulSoup;from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.example.com/")
source = driver.page_source
driver.close()
with open("test.html","wb") as W:
    W.write(source)

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.encode("utf-8"),"html.parser")#.encode("utf-8")
print(soup.find_all("img"))
```

Any Idea about making it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I solved it!
the problem here is because of Arabic language.
Simply ignore the Arabic text from the content by using:
`.encode("utf-8","ignore")`

but first you have to make soup as string so:

`str(soup.find("span","captcha-container")).encode("utf-8","ignore")`